# trying to run rails_upgrade plugin and getting a fork() error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I am investigating whether I should upgrade from rails 2.3.5 to rails 3, so installed the upgrade plugin and ran it:

```
rake rails:upgrade:check
```

Got an error:

```
** Invoke rails:upgrade:check (first_time)
** Execute rails:upgrade:check
rake aborted!
fork() function is unimplemented on this machine
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem. You need to install the `win32-open3` gem (`gem install win32-open3`) and then edit this file in your webapp:

```
vendor\plugins\rails_upgrade\lib\application_checker.rb
```

and change:

```
require 'open3'
```

to:

```
require 'win32/open3'
```

Comment: thanks, will check it out -- prolly save my life if this works.

Comment: No dice. I tried this, but got either "win32-open3 requires Ruby version < 1.9.0" (when using Ruby 1.9.2) or, surprisingly "no such file to load -- win32/open3" (when using Ruby 1.8.7). Interestingly "require 'win32/open3'" works from irb, but not from application_checker.rb.

Comment: @JohannesBrodwall - I'm sure you figured out by now that you needed to add:  gem 'win32-open3'  to your Gemfile, but maybe this comment will be of help to the next person like me who stops by here...